# How to have an itemize/enumerate environment with a smartdiagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

I am trying to make an outline for my work and I thought [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320088/smartdiagram-package-different-fill-color-in-additionals) might be a very good one. However, I failed to add a list under each category.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321809/smartdiagram-tabular-inside-additions-nodes) explains how to include a table in smartdiagram, yet the same thing failed for me.

Here is a MWE. It is actually copy paste of the two linked questions. It returns `Something is wrong, perhaps a missing \item`. Since this is a very general error message I cannot proceed any further.

```
\documentclass[border=100]{standalone}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
% xcolor manual: 34
\definecolorseries{colours}{hsb}{grad}[hsb]{.575,1,1}{.987,-.234,0}
\resetcolorseries[12]{colours}


\begin{document}
\newsavebox\outputbox
\sbox\outputbox{%
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Corr
        \item Corr2
    \end{itemize}
}


\centering
\smartdiagramset{
    set color list={red!10, red!30,red!50},
    sequence item border color=black,
    sequence item text color=black,
    sequence item border size=1.2\pgflinewidth,
    sequence item font size=\scriptsize\sffamily,
    additions={
        additional item shape=rectangle,
        additional item fill color=colours!!+!20,
        additional item border color=colours!!,
        additional arrow line width=2pt,
        additional arrow tip=to,
        additional arrow color=black,
        additional item font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
      }
}
\smartdiagramadd[sequence diagram]{step 1,step 2, step 3}
{below of sequence-item1/a \usebox{\outputbox} ,below of sequence-item2/output 1,below of sequence-item3/output 2}
\smartdiagramconnect{-to}{sequence-item1/additional-module1}
\smartdiagramconnect{-to}{sequence-item2/additional-module2}
\smartdiagramconnect{-to}{sequence-item3/additional-module3}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411852/building-smartdiagram-process-sequence-diagram

Comment: you may like to add a handrawn sketch of your desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may point you in the right direction

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{%
    \setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt, parsep=0pt,
        leftmargin=2em}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2pt,
    start chain = going right,
    start/.style = {signal, 
                    draw=#1, 
                    fill=#1!30,
                    text width=1cm, 
                    minimum height=0.4cm, 
                    font=\scriptsize,
                    signal pointer angle=120, on chain},
    cont/.style = {start=#1, 
                    signal from=west}
    ]
    
    \node[start=orange](a) {\bfseries Step 1};
    \node[above=5mm of a, 
            rectangle, 
            draw, 
            fill=gray!20,
            minimum height=1mm,
            inner sep=1pt,
            text width=1cm]
            (a1){\scriptsize\sffamily{%
                    AABB \& CC\\
                    \begin{itemize}
                    \item X
                    \item Y
                    \end{itemize}   }};
    \node[cont=olive] {\bfseries Step2};
    \node[cont=gray](b) {\bfseries Step3};
    \draw[-latex](a1)to(a);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

edited from --https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411852/building-smartdiagram-process-sequence-diagram

[Smartdiagram Package: Different Fill Color in Additionals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320088/smartdiagram-package-different-fill-color-in-additionals)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I will accept it as soon as I can reproduce it myself :)